# File icon on product page woocomerce will not disappear

Tags: css, woocommerce, file-icons

On my website I have several products for sale using printifil's integration with woo commerce. At first there was a white box over my product title to the left. I removed the product title to leave the white box on a white background hoping it wouldn't be noticed. Now I have a image file icon in replace of the white box. Is there any code I cause use to remove the file icon? I have no idea whats causing the white box or the file icon to appear on the single products page. Here is a link to one of the singe product pages to see what I'm taling about https://www.dontcursekids.com/product/dont-curse-kids-og-hoodie-logo-on-back/. The file icon is above the product image to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below css it will work for you

```
.site-main .figure .fa-file-photo-o {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you Rahul! marked this as the solution and gave you one up. you're a life saver.

Comment: Happy to help :)